# Difference between certificate and digital signature

Tags: certificates, digital-signature

What is the difference between a digital certificate and a digital signature?

Read on the internet that the digital signature is the result of encrypting with a private key, the 'hash' of the message to be sent. As for the digital certificate it is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **digital signature** is a type of cryptographic code that can be attached to a digital document to prove that it comes from a specific party and hasn't been altered or forged. It works by using asymmetric cryptography, which means there is a **key pair** consisting of a **private key** that the **signer** (the party that protects the document) uses to produce the digital signature, and a **public key** that the **verifiers** use to verify the document matches the signature and thus hasn't been adulterated.

A **public key certificate** is a digital document that includes four elements:

1. A description of a party called the **issuer**
2. A description of a party called the **subject**
3. A **public key** that the issuer certifies belongs to the subject
4. A digital signature by the issuer that protects the previous items from tampering or forgery

Certificates address one of the practical problems of using digital signatures: verifiers need to have the signer's public key, but how can they know they've got an authentic key instead of a malicious third-party forgery?  The solution certificates implement is to delegate the job of authenticating keys to an issuer that the verifiers already trust.  So the signer presents you not just with their public key (item #3), but with a certificate that includes that key and that you can verify to convince yourself that they really are who they say they are and that the enclosed public key really is theirs.

Note this kicks the problem back because now you have to obtain an authentic copy of the issuer's key, but the idea is that a few issuers can issue thousands of certificates and thus save you the work of verifying lots of individual subjects' keys.

---

Note that what you read in the internet that signatures "encrypt" a hash is [a common misconception](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43894/asymmetry-between-public-key-and-private-key-digital-signatures-use-the-private).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that "encrypting" the hash is a misconception, and a very popular one.

Answer (score 1):

A Digital Certificate is essentially a message digitally signed by your CA, containing your public key plus some metadata describing who you are. The CA essentially attests that they have validated the metadata according to their [certification practice statement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certification_Practice_Statement) and that they have verified that the entity specified in the metadata controls the private key that corresponds to the public key in the certificate.

In the x509 certificate system, this message is written in a machine readable format that allows the certificate to be used to verify the identity of TLS connections or authors of document signed by the entity specified in the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

A **digital signature** is a technique that verifies the authenticity of the digital document in which particular code is attached to the message that acts as a signature. A hash of the message is utilized for the creation of the message and after that message is encrypted with the sender’s private key. The signature ensures the source and integrity of the message.

A **Digital Certificate** is simply a computer file which helps in establishing your identity. It officially approves the relation between the holder of the certificate (the user) and a particular public key. Thus, a digital certificate should include the user name and the user’s public key. This will prove that the certain public key owned by a particular user.

**Key Differences Between Digital Signature and Digital Certificate**

1. The digital signature proves the authenticity of the digital document. On the other hand, digital certificate identifies the website.
2. A digital certificate is digitally signed and can be used to sign other documents digitally. Digital signature of CA is verified on the digital certificate.
3. Digital certificate creation process includes key generation, registration, verification and creation steps. In contrast, Digital signature process includes encryption and decryption of the message at the sender’s and receiver’s end respectively.

**Summary**

Digital Signature and Digital Certificate both are used for ensuring the authenticity of the digital document although these are absolutely different things. A document is digitally signed to protect it from tampering while Digital Certificate increases the trustworthiness of the website.

[Source: techdifferences.com](https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-digital-signature-and-digital-certificate.html)

Comment: Signature is not encryption with the sender's private key. This is only happening in RSA and that still needs different padding for encryption and signature, see [Search Results
Web results
RSA Signing is Not RSA Decryption - Cornell CS](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2015sp/notes/rsa_sign_vs_dec.php). Also, two  different keys are preferred, one for encryption and one for signature.